# 'removeChild' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: swift, internals

'removeChild' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level
Extra argument 'in' in call

```
removeChild(bottomSheet)
addChild(bottomSheet, in: view)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the method you are looking for. This is how you remove a child view controller from it's parent:

```
    viewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
    viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    viewController.removeFromParent()
```

It looks like you're trying to remove `bottomSheet`, so replace `viewController` in my code with that.

Comment: Thank you!! It works, but what about addChild? it keeps giving me an in: is extra (btw the codes are in different lines, not related or in the same function)

Comment: @hi1231bye Step 1: `addChild(yourViewController)`, Step 2: `view.addSubview(yourViewController.view)`, Step 3: `yourViewController.didMove(toParent: self)`

Comment: All these lines should be ran from the parent view controller, the one you are adding the children to.

Comment: Thank you so much!! But, do you happen to know why it's not showing up? I used OverlawContainer pods but my Xcode is not detecting it, it had a function called, addChild(_ child: UIViewController, in containerView: UIView) and inside it, it's similar to what you have except it has a child.view.pinToSuperview(), child being the viewController